# Función para comparar dos dataframe en python

Tags: python, dataframe

Necesito crear una función que me permita comparar dos dataframe que tienen 10 columnas por 100 filas y como resultado me arroje el porcentaje de compatibilidad (en número) entre los dos.

yo intenté esto:

```py
def compare(a,b):
    a = Dataframe1
    b = Dataframe2

print(Dataframe1 == Dataframe2)
compare(Dataframe1,Dataframe2)
```

Pero claramente estoy lejos del resultado que necesito.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el [tour], tu pregunta necesita algunas mejoras e información para que podamos ayudarte mejor. El primer lugar, hace falta que definas lo que para ti, o tu proyecto, significa compatibilidad. Esto podría ser desde algo muy simple, como lo muestras en tu intento al revisar si dos dataframes son exactamente iguales, o comparar el tamaño (números de filas y columnas) o tan complicado como comparar nombres de las columnas y texto de las celdas con NPL para ver si se parecen, revisar todas las posibles combinaciones de orden

Comment: Entre otras muchas cosas. Entre el punto avanzado que expuse y el básico hay miles de posibles puntos de aceptación dependiendo de lo que consideres compatible. Por lo tanto la pregunta pasa de ser de cómo realizar el programa a algo totalmente diferente que es definir las especificaciones del proyecto. Te recomiendo primero definir tu proyecto, es decir, que deseas comparar (Tamaño, nombres de columnas y texto, orden de datos, todas las posibles combinaciones) y al intentar cada punto entonces publicar preguntas más específicas

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.